# How to use checkbox for selectall by using ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs

**Here i have created a record using ng-grid but wat i need is when i select the selectAll checkbox the selected records should appear in the same page .when i unselect any checkbox in a record the tick mark in selectAll checkbox should not appear in the checkbox the same example which we use in our g-mail plz help me wit this**

-----here is my index.html-------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" 
                   ng-model="allChecked" 
            ng-click="checkAll()" /> Select All
        </label>
        <span ng-model="person.check" ng-click="changeCheckAll()">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ></div>
        </span>



        <span ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {check:true}">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions1" ></div>
        </span>  

    </body>
</html>
```

**And here is my script...**

-------script.js-------

```
// Code goes here

// script.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [{
    name: "Moroni",
    age: 50,

  }, {
    name: "Tiancum",
    age: 43,

  }, {
    name: "Jacob",
    age: 27,

  }, {
    name: "Nephi",
    age: 29,

  }, {
    name: "Enos",
    age: 34,

  }];


   $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'people',
    columnDefs: [{field: 'check',
      displayName: 'Check',
      cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox">'
    }, {
      field: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age'
    },  {
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    }]
  };






    $scope.gridOptions1 = {
    data: 'people',
    columnDefs: [ {
      field: 'age',
      displayName: 'Age'
    },  {
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    }]
  };


 $scope.checkAll = function() {
        for(var i=0; i < $scope.people.length; i++) {
            $scope.people[i].check = $scope.allChecked;
        }
    };


    $scope.changeCheckAll = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.people.length; i++) {

            if (!$scope.people[i].check) {
                $scope.allChecked = false;
                return false;
            }
        }


        $scope.allChecked = true;
    };
});
```

*here is my plnkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/ubatnOV83gz1sF3zaVTf?p=preview*

Comment: your ng-model="person.check" should be inside ng-repeat block

Comment: But even now I'm getting the same answer.....

Answer (score 0):

Use showSelectionCheckbox to set grid options. Here is the link
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/